# reduce file size of exported leaflet html by linking several layers to the same data (json) instead of keeping the information separately

Tags: r, r-leaflet, r-mapview, htmltools

Generating leaflet html's easily results in a 50-75 MB file (depending on the number of layers). However, they can be zipped to reduce the file size by factors. So i guess there is lots of repetitive information in the HTML. The data is the same for most of the layers.

Simplifying the geometries would help, but I don't want to alter them. I further red, that GeoJson plots all the boundaries of polygons, even if they are bordering each other, but I didn't succeed down that line.

Any idea on how to do that? I included the mapview-tag as it seems to me that mapview is more data efficient.

The following code creates a simple map with a number of identical layers. Adding two layers, results in 3.7 MB (zip to 1.4), adding 20 layers (with the same information), results in 32.6 MB (zip to 12.9).

```
library(leaflet)
library(htmlwidgets)
nrep <- 2
colors <- colorFactor(palette="viridis",
                      domain=gadmCHE@data$NAME_1, na.color="transparent")
mapCH <- gadmCHE %>% leaflet() %>% addTiles() 

for (i in 1:nrep){
  print(i)
  mapCH <- mapCH %>% 
    addPolygons(fillColor = ~colors(NAME_1), fillOpacity = 1,group = as.character(i))
}
mapCH <- mapCH %>% 
    addLayersControl(position = "topleft", 
                     baseGroups = c("OpenStreetMap"),
                     options = layersControlOptions(collapsed=F),
                     overlayGroups=paste(1:nrep)) %>%
   clearControls()%>%
   hideGroup(paste(1:nrep))

saveWidget(mapCH, file = paste0("Test_",nrep,".html"), selfcontainted = F)
```

It seems all the vertex from all the polygons are put within the `html` as `json`. So if one could gather all the duplicated coordinates and replace them by a link to a `json`, either placed in a separate folder or within the `html`, that could solve the problem.

Comment: I have two comments: 1) mapview is built on top of leaflet so it is not either / or - but yes, mapview has some optimizations, such as using geobuf 2) the logic of {leaflet} R package does not allow re-using geometry definition between layers. In theory this should be possible in `leaflet.js` directly, but would require you to work in javascript

Comment: thanks! So is mapview re-using the geometry when coding something like `mapview(leaflet::gadmCHE, burst=T)`? I then would need to figure out how to apply different color scales to each layer... or eventually learn javascript.

Comment: to be honest I don't really know. The optimizations that mapview applies are over & beyond my (very limited) javascript knowledge

Comment: Many thanks, this is already very helpful! I could imagine user:2555983 (TimSalabim) might know more about the internals of mapview ;-)

Comment: I do, but everything really depends on the concrete use-case. The optimisations mentioned are mostly about the data model used to pass data between R and JS. I have no idea how to re-use geometries. The `add*` functions provided by leaflet do exactly what they say, they add a layer to the map, even if it is already present. I haven't investigated how to avoid data duplication TBH.

Comment: What I found: If you use `mapview(gadmCHE)@map %>% saveWidget(file = "Test_mapview",selfcontained = F)` the data gets added as a FlatGeobuf (.fdg) in a separate folder.  Whereas `leaflet(gadmCHE) %>% addTiles() %>% addPolygons(fillColor = ~colors(NAME_1), fillOpacity = 0.8) %>% saveWidget(file = "Test_leaflet.html",selfcontained = F)` it seems all the vertex from all the polygons are put within the html as json.

Comment: Yes - Leaflet maps created this way will copy the data for each layer. There are various approaches that could avoid this. Will your output html file be accessed locally or on a server? If a local file, there can't be accompanying data files. If on a server, you _could_ try to roll your own solution which pulls the json out of the html, cuts out the shared part, compresses it and then reconstructs both maps from this. But if you have a server anyway and you want an R solution then I think it would be easier to use Shiny to draw the polygons you need.

Comment: Im pushing the html to our webserver. The webserver is static. I never installed a Shiny server, but this could of course be a way forward. For the time being, I would prefer some solution to "pull the json out of the html" and "cut out the shared part".

Comment: Have you seen [Load Quarto html map data from json for Leaflet map generated in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77448028/load-quarto-html-map-data-from-json-for-leaflet-map-generated-in-r/77473333)? I think you could do something like this but it would need to be extended quite a lot (this just moves the embedded Leaflet json from the html to separate json files but doesn't try to identify common parts). It wouldn't be straightforward and I think would be fairly fragile to changes in the data or Leaflet. I would just use Shiny if it's an option - it will be much more robust.

Comment: the package `leafgl` https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/leafgl/ allows to "to pass data to the widget via file attachments". This could be a way forward to then replace fewer lines within the `HTML`.