# Find data inside shareable embedded html file from Quarto

Tags: r, dashboard, quarto

I would like to know if it is possible to find the data behind an embedded html Quarto dashboard file. Imagine you want to share an html but I want to be sure that the data shown in the file is not extractable from that html file. In the example below I use the Palmerpenguins dataset:

````
---
title: "Palmer Penguins"
author: "Quinten"
format: 
  dashboard:
    embed-resources: true
logo: penguins.png
theme: 
  - zephyr
---

```{r}
# import packages
library(tidyverse)
library(crosstalk)
library(DT)
library(plotly)
library(gt)
library(palmerpenguins)

# import data
penguins <- palmerpenguins::penguins

# Crosstalk dataset
shared_penguins <- SharedData$new(penguins)

# Set theme
theme_set(theme_minimal())
```

# {.sidebar}

This is a simple static dashboard to show what is possible with the newest version of [Quarto v1.4](https://quarto.org/docs/blog/posts/2024-01-24-1.4-release/). To make it a bit interactive we use the [crosstalk](https://github.com/rstudio/crosstalk) package and [plotly](https://plotly.com/r/).

***

In this dashboard we visualize the [palmerpenguins](https://allisonhorst.github.io/palmerpenguins/) dataset. In the table below is some basic information about the data:

| Specie       |  Count             |
|--------------|---------------------|
| **Adelie**     | `{r} nrow(subset(penguins, species == "Adelie"))`  |
| **Gentoo**   | `{r} nrow(subset(penguins, species == "Gentoo"))`   |
| **Chinstrap**  | `{r} nrow(subset(penguins, species == "Chinstrap"))` |

```{r}
filter_checkbox("sex", "Sex", shared_penguins, ~sex)
```

***

# Analysis

## Row {height=40%}

### Column {width=80%}

```{r}
#| title: "Slider options"
slider_width = 800
htmltools::div(
    id = "sliderdiv", 
    filter_slider("bill_length_mm", "bill length", shared_penguins, ~bill_length_mm, width = slider_width),
    filter_slider("bill_depth_mm", "bill depth", shared_penguins, ~bill_depth_mm, width = slider_width),
    filter_slider("flipper_length_mm", "flipper length", shared_penguins, ~flipper_length_mm, width = slider_width),
    filter_slider("body_mass_g", "body mass", shared_penguins, ~body_mass_g, width = slider_width)
)
```

### Column {width=20%}

```{r}
#| content: valuebox
#| title: "Number of penguins"
list(
  icon = "tencent-qq",
  color = "primary",
  value = nrow(penguins)
)
```

## Row {height=60%}

```{r}
#| title: "Flipper length vs body mass"
p <- ggplot(shared_penguins, aes(x = flipper_length_mm, y = body_mass_g, color = species, shape = species)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("darkorange","darkorchid","cyan4")) 

ggplotly(p)
```

```{r}
#| title: "bill length by species"
p <- ggplot(data = penguins, aes(x = species, y = bill_length_mm)) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_jitter(aes(color = species),
              width = 0.1, 
              alpha = 0.7,
              show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("darkorange","darkorchid","cyan4"))
ggplotly(p)
```

# Table

Table of the palmerpenguins dataset. You can use the sliders and checkboxes to filter the table.

```{r}
DT::datatable(shared_penguins)
```

# Citation

```{r, echo=FALSE}
citation("palmerpenguins")
```
````

Imagine the file is now called `dashboard_palmerpenguins.html`, now I would like to know if the dataset is extractable in some way.  FYI, I don't want the data to be searchable even when you don't send the dataset (for example csv or anything else).

So I was wondering if there is any way to extract the data that is used inside an HTML from Quarto?

Comment: Hate to say it but the data is extremely extractable from the html. Open the html in a text editor and find a tag starting with somethig like `<script type="application/json" data-for="htmlwidget-">`. The data is just sitting in plain text as a big json blob. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77448028/load-quarto-html-map-data-from-json-for-leaflet-map-generated-in-r) question for a Python script to remove it and put it in a separate json file. That was only to make the html size smaller. Fundamentally, if you want to hide the data, a Quarto dashboard is not going to work.

Comment: @SamR, Thank you for your answer! That is unfortunate to hear. Hopefully, there will be one day a way to share this without having the data inside the file...

Comment: As long as you include interactive visualizations and tables the data will always have to be in the HTML somewhere. If you only include static plots, like the ggplots in your example, the data wouldn't be included in the HTML. Depending on the type and detail of the plot someone can still deduct details of the underlying dataset.